# Converting base64 encoded geometry to WKT

Tags: well-known-text, well-known-binary

An element in a received XML-file contains the geometry, which I believe is base64-encoded:

```
    <pointData>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</pointData>
```

When I try to decode it to binary or hex, eg. using https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-binary, it doesn't make much sense, and I haven't been able to translate it further into WKT.

I believe the geometry is a polygon, and I would expect it to begin with 010300 when decoded to hex. But it seems to be  random, and I havent spotted a system in the 10-20 elements I checked so far.

Comment: Why do you believe it is base64 encoded?  Looks like it might be an [encoded polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?hl=en) to me (which does use base64 encoding): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/m4hua975/)

Comment: It just doesn't ring any other bells. Nice wok getting some sort of geometry from the string, although I'd expect the coordinate system to be 25832.